# Getting Segmentation fault while traversing linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I've simple C++ program to traverse a linked list.
It runs perfectly in [ideone](https://ideone.com/IbPspC) .
When I run this in my mac terminal it throws segmentation fault.
When I uncomment `//printf("Node");` line from traverse function it runs perfectly. I'm not able to understand this behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

void traverseLinkedList(Node *start) {
    while(start) {
        //printf("Node");
        cout << start->data << "->";
        start = start->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
}
int main() {
    Node *start = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *a = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *b = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    start->data = 0;
    a->data = 1;
    b->data = 2;
    start->next = a;
    a->next = b;
    traverseLinkedList(start);
    traverseLinkedList(a);
    traverseLinkedList(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where/how are you learning C++?  Besides `cout` this is C code and not how you should be using C++.

Comment: There should never be a reason to use malloc in C++ unless you are maintaining some code that was ported from C.

Comment: Don't include <bits/stdc++.h>.
Don't use malloc in C++.

Comment: Get one of these [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot this statement

```
b->next = nullptr;
```

Otherwise the program has undefined behavior due to the condition in this while statement in the function `traverseLinkedList`

```
while(start)
```

Take into account that in C++ you should use the operator `new` instead of the C function `malloc`.

For example

```
Node *b = new Node { 3, nullptr };
Node *a = new Node { 2, b };
Node *start = new Node { 1, a };
```

And you should free the allocated memory before exiting the program.

Comment: But why did this ran successfully on ideone https://ideone.com/IbPspC. Default value for such pointer is NULL?

Comment: @RohitPal It means as I wrote in my answer that the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm getting `error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        Node *b = new Node {2, nullptr};`. same error for init of `a` and `start` node.

Comment: @RohitPal Maybe your compiler does not support this syntax of initialization. In this case write for example Node *b = new Node; b->data = 3; b->next = nullptr; or b->bext = NULL;